# pytorch running: RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

When I running the python code, there is a runtimeError in line 44:**RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!**

```
    42  feats = self.node_features[self.train_mask]
    43  labels = self.node_labels[train_mask]

    44  A = torch.mm(feats.t(), feats) + 1e-05 * torch.eye(feats.size(1))

    45  labels_one_hot = torch.zeros((feats.size(0), self.n_classes))
```

Can anyone who knows the reason and help me fix it!  Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to sum 2 tensors, one is on CPU (the identity matrix you define using ```torch.eye```) and the other on GPU (```feats```). So, in line 44 add ```.to('cuda')``` as follows: ```torch.eye(feats.size(1)).to('cuda')``` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the tensor torch.eye(...) is on CPU.
you need to pass it as -

```
44  A = torch.mm(feats.t(), feats) + 1e-05 * torch.eye(feats.size(1)).to(device='cuda')
```

or

```
44  A = torch.mm(feats.t(), feats) + 1e-05 * torch.eye(feats.size(1)).cuda()
```

Comment: Thanks, had the same error with `torch.FloatTensor([n])`. Changing to `torch.FloatTensor([n]).cuda()` fixed it.